# Create a Link To An External Page On Order Confirmation Page in Prestashop

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm very naive. I am not able to create an external hyperlink on the order confirmation page. (lets say http://google.com)

I've modified the bank transfer module to create a manual payment method, but I am not able to add a simple link on the confirmation page. The screenshot depicts it well.

Also attaching the screenshot of the backend where I input the text. I've tried editing the tpl files, but it doesn't change the actual code on the browser. I have even tried disabling html filter and typing href on the text box itself, again the code just disappears in the browser.

The images will make things very clear.

Thanks.
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeYDk.png)
[Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDWne.png)

Comment: Modifying the tpl file is the solution to your problem. Can you paste the code from your tpl file ?
Also, did you try disabling cache in Advanced settings > Performances ?

Comment: Yes, after clearing the cache, it works! Thanks a lot! Can't believe I couldn't figure it out in 4 hours!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, like ébewè said, go to advanced settings > Performances, and clear cache or select no from the drop-down menu next to cache.

Then you can just use high school grade html commands in tpl file to wrap the requisite text inside the code. It works!

Thanks ébewè!